# Infinitesimal variation of spectrum of Schrödinger operator with changing domain

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, schrodinger-operators

Suppose we have a Schrödinger operator

$$-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$$

defined on $[a,b]$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions. I am interested in whether there are any results for the variation of the spectrum $\{\lambda_i\}$ with changing $a$ and $b$, i.e. the quantities

$$\frac{\partial \lambda_i}{\partial a}, \frac{\partial \lambda_i}{\partial b}$$

I assume that $V(x)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, so that changing the endpoints will also lead to the inclusion of new parts of the potential.

Comment: An obvious remark is that $\partial\lambda_j/\partial a>0$. Introducing an extra boundary condition is a rank one perturbation of the resolvent, so there's a lot of theory you can apply here.

Comment: Thanks Christian... could you elaborate what you mean by "extra" boundary condition? I want to move the boundary.

Comment: You can consider the sum of the operators on $L^2(a,a')\oplus L^2(a',b)$ and compare it with the original operator.

Comment: I guess you have to impose some basic smoothness assumption on $V$ to make the question less hopeless. Assume $V=\alpha\delta_{x_0}$, then the spectrum can become very different as soon as you reach $x_0$, playing a bit with $\alpha\in \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a=-1$, $b=1$. Expand the endpoints by infinitesimal $\epsilon$. Let $y=\frac{x}{1+\epsilon}$. Then you get an equation  on [-1,1]  with potential of the form $V + \epsilon yV'$, so this can be considered a perturbation problem on a fixed domain.